# Excel VBA using Range returned from Function

Tags: vba, excel

I have this function which returns a Range:

```
Private Function getInvestorsCompanyRange()
    Dim companyStart As range
    Dim lastRow As range
    If Len(Trim(investorsCompanyRange.value)) = 0 Then
             getInvestorsCompanyRange = range("A1")
    Else
            Set lastRow = investorsCompanyRange.End(xlDown)
             getInvestorsCompanyRange = range(investorsCompanyRange, lastRow)
    End If
End Function
```

And this function for getting the right value from that Range according to Combo Box I have in my Form:

```
Private Sub cmbNoteName_Change()
    Dim investorsRange As range
    Set investorsRange = getInvestorsCompanyRange

    lblNoteCompany.Caption = investorsNameRange.Rows.Offset(cmbNoteName.ListIndex).value
End Sub
```

I keep getting object is required.. I know that the getInvestorsCompanyRange return the right range because when i'm trying to assign it to a combo box list - it shows the right values.

Comment: Where is **investorsCompanyRange** being **Dim** 'ed and **Set** ??

Comment: @AsafNevo  **which line** causes the "object is required" error?

Comment: Try fully qualifying lblNoteCompany and cmbNoteName

Comment: Its the 'Set investorsRange = getInvestorsCompanyRange'
and investorsCompanyRange is set as global variable once the document is being loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `Set` to assign the return value from your function: without Set (and because you've not specified your function's return type) you will instead return the *value* of the Range instead of the range itself.

```
Private Function getInvestorsCompanyRange() As Range
    Dim companyStart As range
    Dim lastRow As range
    If Len(Trim(investorsCompanyRange.value)) = 0 Then
            Set getInvestorsCompanyRange = Range("A1")
    Else
            Set lastRow = investorsCompanyRange.End(xlDown)
            Set getInvestorsCompanyRange = Range(investorsCompanyRange, lastRow)
    End If
End Function
```